# how to set proxy for firefox using java?

Tags: java, linux, squid

I am trying to develop an app which will take ip address as a input and set it as a proxy in clients firefox as a proxy. The idea here is , I am trying to gain access to squid server through java? is there any possibility of doing so? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe. I suggest you read through [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23117/configuring-firefox-to-use-a-proxy-from-the-command-line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your Java application to use Charles in code or as command line arguments to the java executable.

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");

And for HTTPS as well. Note that you may also want to configure Java to trust Charles’s root certificate in this case (see SSL Proxying).

System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");

Comment: Firefox doesn't honor those environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

proxy settings for Firefox are stored in prefs.js file of user

%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\7a3fd5zw.default\prefs.js

here 7a3fd5zw is a random string. 
There are settings named "network.proxy.http"  and "network.proxy.http_port".

May be, you can try to modify them.

Comment: That's not for Firefox.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah, I misunderstood the question. I have updated my answer. thanks for pointing it out.